# Xamarin Forms Android - How to Enable Proguard Shrinker in Visual Studio for Mac 2019

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, proguard

I am trying to invoke Proguard Code Shrinker for my XF 5.x Android Application in Visual studio for Mac 2019.

It looks like I need the Windows version from the Documentation. Is that true?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/proguard?tabs=macos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but the equivalent place to find the option on Mac is:

> rt-click on your Android project / Options / Build / Android Build / Code Shrinker.

There you'll see choices

- proguard
- r8

Apparently `r8` is the recommended choice - click the (i) icon next to Code Shrinker dropdown for an explanation.